# How I insert birthday in user plone?

Tags: user-interface, overriding, plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

I use Plone 4.3.9, and I'm doing a intranet, all users come from Samba4.

But, I created a new dexterity content types (with this fields Name, Photo, and birthday [Day and Year]) and in index page to show up and I handler users and birthday to appear in index

I want put in garbage the way that I do (described up), and to expand my knowledge in Plone, I want override users Plone or do something like to put one or two more fields to set month and year of birthday in default users plone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Plone 4 and 5 Plone data is controlled by [plone.app.users](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.users/).

On Plone 4 you must rely on this tutorial: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.examples.userdata/2.1